# Full titles for Youtube channel's videos

Tags: youtube

Let's suppose you have opened some Youtube channel. Youtube channel's videos have their titles trimmed if they're longer than several words. This makes learning the content of the channel very inconvenient - you have to hover over a video to see its full title.

Is it possible to configure/change Youtube channel list of videos so that full titles are shown?

For example, when you use the channel search tool (a magnifying glass in the upper-right corner of the channel page) then the search results have full titles.

Answer (score 1):

Install **TamperMonkey** in your browser and add the below script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         YouTube Longer Name Script
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  make longer names to avoid trucate
// @author       Sergiu Elmi
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var videoTitles = document.querySelectorAll('#video-title');
    videoTitles.forEach(function(title) {
    title.style.cssText = "max-height: 7 rem !important; font-size: 1.2 rem !important; overflow: initial !important; display: initial !important;";
        });
})();
```